# Read complete content of .rtf document

Tags: php, html, rtf

I have to create a document using user inserted data and including data from a .rtf document into a web page layout i created (HTML+CSS and PHP for scripting).

My problem is, i can't find any way to obtain the full content of the .rtf document.
Being a technical document symbols, tables, graphs and images are very often included: with the methods I've found i could obtain the text with symbols in a decent formatting but i had no luck with images.

So what i need is a way to obtain the full content of a .rtf file, possibly maintaining the document formatting, so i can display and organize it in a webpage; preferrably in pure PHP but use of js/executables via php is fine.

I've tried:
-rtf to html converters but the best i could get is clear text and symbols but no images;
using COM extension to open the .rtf in ms word and saving it as  .html (i noticed that if i open up the .rtf then save it as webpage in word it creates a perfect html page) but it only changed the extension and didn't create a html page;
extracting text and image sperately: works but again being the document a technical document image placement is very important.

It's my first question here, after many research; please bear with me in case of errors.

Comment: Have you considered converting to pdf and then embedding

Comment: @IsmailM Yes, but my superior wants the data to be editable if needed and not just displayed; also sometimes I would need to extract only some parts of the doc and not the whole of it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Do you have an example Rtf document available that I can play about with.